# Invalid JSON request: Syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Доброй ночи, возникла такая проблема:
При отправке POST запроса (с указанием `cookie`, `proxy` и `header`) возвращает

> Invalid JSON request: Syntax error.

Но все остальные запросы отрабатывает нормально. Единственное отличие между рабочими и нерабочими запросами это наличие `content-length` в `requests headers`. Пробовал ставить `data`, `params` - ничего не помогает.

`headers`:

```
{
  'authority': 'onlyfans.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'app-token': '33d57ade8c02dbc5a333db99ff9ae26a',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'origin': 'https://onlyfans.com',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'x-bc': 'bbddbf8abe17ae75b01ad31ea843ba97a5872713',
  'time': '1675728377',
  'user-id': '250186326',
  'sign': '6820:c03cee1159b91182026b2ff89455662e2755fa9f:83c:63d81407'
}
```

`cookie`:

```
{
  'fp': 'c9eb5fcdc40dd97bdd4a30e074eb6910',
  'sess': 'bamr1g1okq4kcd7njhke2sf9dl',
  'st': 'd36a2f05594e1d43180bb277b3e367f0d633ffd20ad64811f9b7ff7fec466597',
  'auth_id': '250186326',
  'ref_src': '',
  'cookiesAccepted': 'all',
  'csrf': 'OjWOR7EIc85bb051c9fd8b7f34c306778fe40028'
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Скорее всего пропустили какую-нибудь кавычку или запятую. Более конкретно нельзя сказать, не видя вашего джсона.

Comment: `{'authority': 'onlyfans.com', 'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'app-token': '33d57ade8c02dbc5a333db99ff9ae26a', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'origin': 'https://onlyfans.com', 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'x-bc': 'bbddbf8abe17ae75b01ad31ea843ba97a5872713', 'time': '1675728377', 'user-id': '250186326', 'sign': '6820:c03cee1159b91182026b2ff89455662e2755fa9f:83c:63d81407'}`
это header

Comment: `{'fp': 'c9eb5fcdc40dd97bdd4a30e074eb6910', 'sess': 'bamr1g1okq4kcd7njhke2sf9dl', 'st': 'd36a2f05594e1d43180bb277b3e367f0d633ffd20ad64811f9b7ff7fec466597', 'auth_id': '250186326', 'ref_src': '', 'cookiesAccepted': 'all', 'csrf': 'OjWOR7EIc85bb051c9fd8b7f34c306778fe40028'}` - cookie

Comment: это все работает в других запросах, в get всегда без ошибок отрабатывает

Comment: Добавьте сам код в вопрос, первый комментарий все еще актуален.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в `content-type`, его просто нужно было удалить